# upgrade 14.04 with errors

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04. I got computer not stable and upgrade aborted and recover to old version, but I let it continue to complete. It says upgrade complete with errors. It did not process clean up and I checked about this computer it says Ubuntu 14.04

After I reboot the computer, it shows Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, it seems that I completed the update. My question is the update the message confuse me, it looks like the update with errors and aborted, but at the end it shows that it is 14.04. I am not sure which version I have right now. If I am on 14.04, how about those errors during update how I can know what were the errors and how I can fix those errors during upgrade?

Your help and information is great appreciated,

Iccsi

Answer (score 1):

In a command prompt run:

```
lsb_release -a
```

That will let you know what version you have installed.
If in doubt, you can always fix an incomplete upgrade with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If while that is running you get errors, then you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

then repeat

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That should fix any broken 13.10 packages that did not upgrade properly to 14.04